# Kolmogorov Smirnov statistic for a location scale family

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have the following homework question.

Consider the location-scale family generated by a fixed, specified, distribution function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$, so

$$F_{\mu,\sigma}(x)=F\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right), \mu\in\mathbb{R}, \sigma>0.$$

Let $\hat{\mu}_n=t_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a location-scale equivariant estimate for $\mu$, and let $\hat{\sigma}_n=s_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a location invariant and scale equivariant estimate for $\sigma$. Consider the composite hypothesis of the type: $F$ belongs to the class $\{F_{\mu,\sigma}: \mu\in\mathbb{R}, \sigma>0\}$. Show that the distribution of

$$K_n=\sup_{x\,\in\,\mathbb{R}}\left|F_{\hat{\mu}_n,\hat{\sigma}_n}(x)-\mathbb{F}_n(x)\right|$$
does not depend on the underlying $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

My attempt so far:
I know that $\mathbb{F}_n$ is the empirical distribution. The "invariant" and "equivariant" descriptions of the estimators mean that for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta>0$,

$$t_n(\alpha+\beta x_1,\ldots,\alpha+\beta x_n)=\alpha+\beta t_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\\
s_n(\alpha+\beta x_1,\ldots,\alpha+\beta x_n)=\beta s_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$

I think I have to show that if I have a sample from a distribution $F_{\mu_1,\sigma_1}$ and a second sample from a distribution $F_{\mu_2,\sigma_2}$, then I end up with the same distribution for the value of $K_n$, but I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: When the location-scale family is the family of normal distributions, then the distribution of the maximum-discrepancy statistic is called the Liliefors distribution. Last I heard, nobody knew how to compute quantiles of the Liliefors distribution except by numerical methods and there isn't even a non-closed-form formula for it, such as an integral. But that was more than a decade ago. (However, the exercise you're trying to do -- merely showing that the distribution does not depend on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ -- is a far simpler matter.)

Comment: I would let $\mu_2=0$ and $\sigma_2=1.$ If you can show it in that case, then you've got it.